# Centralising module settings and model administration

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a module where I need to:

- Manage Models
- Manage Module Settings

  - API Authentication
  - Look & Feel
  - Etc

For **Manage Models** I obviously have a `ModelAdmin` extension

And for the latter **Manage Module Settings** I've had to create a `DataExtension`

Though this splits up the "Module Functionality" into two sections, `ModelAdmin` gets its own menu item on the sidebar, but the `DataExtension` only adds tabs to the **Settings** menu item.

I've searched around but to no avail on how to consolidate my custom tabs within the same menu item that `ModelAdmin` creates.

Is this possible? I understand the semantics behind `ModelAdmin` being that it only Administers Models but surely the functionality exists where you can add tabs to the menu item it creates that aren't models?

Surely it's not an abnormal scenario

Comment: Evidentally I may have to extend `LeftAndMain` which looks like a ballpark of fun

Comment: how about SiteConfig for "Module Settings"?

Comment: `ModelAdmin` and `Settings` (SiteConfig) is standard way of splitting concerns in SilverStripe. If you want to change this, you need to create extension to `ModelAdmin` with `updateEditForm` hook and modify the form with tabs and extra fields. It is not "abnormal scenario" but odd.

Comment: I am using `SiteConfig` via `DataExtension` and to get my config I literally `SiteConfig::current_site_config()` though I would sacrifice this accessibility for consolidation in a heartbeat though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you could do this would be to extend LeftAndMain (as you have mentioned).

This can be a little daunting, but LeftAndMain is basically just a container for 3 templates:

1. Main admin template
2. Left hand nav template
3. Main edit form

At a basic level you can just create an extension to LeftAndMain, then add a custom "EditForm" function that has the settings fields you need (as well as actions to save the data).

Then if you want it to look fancier then you can overwrite the default LeftAndMain templates in framework/admin/tempaltes.

There are some docs on this on the Silverstripe site: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/customising_the_admin_interface/cms_layout/

Hope that helps a bit.